# How do I change the displayed file templates on new file creation in WebStorm?

Tags: ide, editor, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

When trying to create a new file in WebStorm, I can't see the file template I'd like to use (in this case - Less). It exists in my File templates, but doesn't show up in the New File selector dropdown.

Here's my New File selector dropdown:

[image]

And here are my File templates:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reduce "New File" menu size, some of the bundled (default) similar file templates are grouped under the single menu entry which has drop down box where you can choose the particular kind of template to use. Examples of such grouped/gateway entries are: "HTML File", "Stylesheet", "JavaScript File", "PHP Class" etc.

In your particular case you need to use **"Stylesheet" entry** where you can choose "Less File":

[image]

Some notes:

1. IDE will remember the "Kind" value that you have used when you use this dialog again.
2. There is no need to use mouse or keyboard to switch to the "Kind" filed at all -- just use <kbd>Arrow Up/Down</kbd> keys when typing file name -- they will switch the "Kind" directly from there.
3. If you create custom file template (e.g. "Less file 2") it will not be grouped/accessible via such dialog -- it will be listed as separate entry in "New" menu.

Comment: Thanks. A combination of your guide and a keyboard shortcut for creating a new Stylesheet did the trick for me. :)